# Link iOS push notification to PWA/website

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, progressive-web-apps

We are in the process of developing a PWA that should send out notifications that are visible outside the application and even when the application is closed. In other words, like when a native app would send out notifications.

However, at the moment this is only possible on Android devices, on iOS this is not yet possible.

So we are looking for ways to work around this problem.

One theory is to create a very small native app for iOS with the soul purpose to send out notifications.

Our PWA would create the notification and make it available via an API call.
The native app would do a request every x seconds to retrieve the notifications and display them on the phone.

The part where we are a bit in the dark about is if it is possible to make the notification that is displayed link to the PWA instead of the native app?

Comment: Yes I think you can just use application.open(url: url) and as your app doesn't handle the link, it will open in browser

Answer (score 0):

Yes maybe with OS X Push Notifications for Websites: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/safari-push-notifications/